# MPMoviePlayerController does not work with movie in documents folder

Tags: ios, stream, mpmovieplayercontroller, mov

I have a ViewController which plays a movie. If the movie was downloaded (with ASI-HTTP-Request) it takes the local version. Otherwise it streams it from the web. It's the exact same movie.

Streaming does work very well, but playing the local file does not work. Just a black screen and no controls. The file has been downloaded correctly I checked the md5 checksum.

It's a Apple QuickTime Video (.mov) at a size of 1024x5xx pixel.

```
player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
[player.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
if (local) {
    // DOES not work
    // SHOULD be [NSURL fileURLWithString:...]
    [player setContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"/path/to/the/movie.mov"]];
} else {
    // does work
    [player setContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://mydomain.tld/path/to/the/movie.mov"]];
}
[self.view addSubview: player.view];
[player play]
```

I tried around with the players MediaSourceType. But it didn't help.
Why does it not work? 
I don't have any error messages because I dont receive one..., is there a way to get error messages from it?

**Solution**

I found my error.

I used `[NSURL URLWithString: @"/the/path/..."]` for the local path.

It works with `[NSURL fileURLWithPath: @"/the/path/..."]`

Answer (score 1):

Check URL to video file. This line return path to Documents directory.

```
NSString* docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
               (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
```

Your path is not related to Document directory

```
[player setContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"/path/to/the/movie.mov"]];
```

Try this

```
[player setContentURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", docPath, @"/path/to/the/movie.mov"]]];
```

Comment: The path is correct, I shorted the code. Sorry about that.
The movie actually sits in the cache directory.

`[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/Library/Caches/movie.mov", NSHomeDirectory()]`

NSFileManager says the file exists...